# Block diagonal matrix as Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, kronecker-product

Let

$$X=\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 0 & A_2 & ... & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & ... & A_n \end{bmatrix}$$

Where the $A_i$ are square but not necessarily equal in dimension.

Is there any way that $X$ can be expressed using Kronecker products of the $A_i$ matrices?

Comment: Could you say what a Kronecker product of two square matrices is, including the case where factors have different dimensions?

Comment: Think of MATLAB function `kron`, which has $2$ inputs. Your block diagonal matrix has $n$ diagonal blocks.